# Привильное написание принадлежности местоположения

Tags: орфография, синтаксис, морфология

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть объект строительства, который находится в Нефтеюганском районе. Подрядчик обозначает район строительства "... объекты расположены в Тюменской области, Ханты-Мансийского Автономного округа, Нефтеюганского района". Прошу исправить на "...расположены в Нефтеюганском р-не, Х-М Автономого округа, Тюменской области", но мои замечания отвергаются. Помогите разобраться, может это я не права? Или как аргументировать свою точку зрения??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В последовательности, предложенной подрядчиком (от общего к частному) записывают только формальный адрес - в именительном падеже. В тексте нужно было бы предварить такое указание словами "по адресу:", сохранив падеж. Склонение же иерархического списка слов из формального адреса может даже создавать ложное впечатление о том, что во что входит ("Тюменская область Х-М округа" - уже ошибка, область больше). Поэтому в вашем варианте склонения последовательность правильная, нужно только убрать запятые - при имеющихся падежах иерархические элементы правильно взаимосвязаны. Ср.: "Есенин родился в селе Константиново Рязанской губернии".